# Setting the jQuery Content-Type field

Tags: jquery, content-type, mime-types

I'm trying to get AJAX POSTing working on my server (Python/Django/Nginx/UWSGI). The problem that I'm running into is that jQuery automatically appends ";charset=utf-8" to the content-type field, no matter what I use to avoid this (setting contentType, or using beforeSend to change it). The problem that this causes, is that my POSTs now get a 400 - Bad Request response from my server. However, if I use Tamper Data to manually remove the ";charset=utf-8" from the Content-Type field, everything works great.

This is from Firefox 3.6.12.

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this (manually removing ";charset=utf-8")? Alternately, can anyone tell me if it's a server issue instead?

Comment: Appears it's a server issue.  Quoting the jQuery ajax API "Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side."     http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a server issue. Firefox always appends the charset to the content-type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160467/834309) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12454034/834309).

As suggested in the accepted answer to the question I linked you can sendAsBinary (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416178#c31). I did not check that out myself, though.