# Firefox augments the content-type of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, content-type

How can FireFox be forced to use a specific content type for XMLHttpRequest without appending the charset parameter after the type itself?

I am using FireFox 15 to extract some data out of a very custom http server. The server takes JSON from the POST body and responds with another JSON. The server accepts only "Content-Type: application/json" as valid content type. Anything after except this exact header will not be recognized by the server as valid content type.

When I use the below code in Chrome it sets the content type as expected "Content-Type: application/json"

```js
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
invocation.open('POST', url, true);
invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
invocation.onreadystatechange = function(data){ /* some processing */ };
invocation.send(body);
```

The issue is that FireFox sets the content type to "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416178#c31) using sendAsBinary is a possible workaround.